# Waiting for the script to stop running to see the result on output file - Windows

Tags: python, cygwin, beautifulsoup

I have written a script that writes it output to a file. I am running the script using CYGWIN on windows. But unlike Ubuntu or MacOS, I have to wait for the script to run completely, until then the output file's size remains zero. Why does that happen in windows alone?

Comment: Try flushing your file once and then.

Comment: Calling `flush()` on the file object.

Comment: Would that let me see the size change of output file while the script is running?

Comment: Depending on the file system, operation system, used driver, etc... but most probably yes. I guess your output is being buffered, either by your python interpreter or by your OS or FS.

Comment: I think that's the default behavior on windows. It's the same when you're downloading something. The changes happens once the process is done.